# JavaScript tabbed interface - how to link and bookmark a tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I’ve created a tabbed interface with jQuery to show/hide content.

I want to be able to link to a particular tab and allow users to bookmark the current tab they are on.

As I use IDs for each containing div I can achieve this by removing `return false;` from the click event but this causes the page to skip down to the containing div for the tab.

Is there a way of ensuring that the URL contains the # part of the address but prevents the page from skipping?  Is there another way of approaching this problem that I haven’t come across yet?

```
//Get all containers with tab content
var tabContainers = $("div.tab");  

//Get value of # from URL
if (window.location.hash) {

  //if there's a # display the relevant tab
  $(tabContainers).hide().filter(window.location.hash).show();  

} else {
    //Show the first tab
    $(tabContainers).hide().filter(":first").show();    
}


$("ul#tabNav a").click( function () {

    //Hide all tab content then display the current
    $(tabContainers).hide().filter(this.hash).show();

    //prevent page from skipping but also prevents # from appearing in address bar
    return false;

});





<div id="tabNavContainer">
    <ul id="tabNav">
        <li id="tab1"> <a href="#a">Course essentials</a> </li>
        <li id="tab2"> <a href="#b">Course details</a> </li>
        <li id="tab3"> <a href="#c">Next steps</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="a">
    <h3>TAB A</h3>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="b">
    <h3>TAB B</h3>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="c">
    <h3>TAB C</h3>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `window.location.hash` as well as reading it:

```
$("ul#tabNav a").click( function () {

    //Hide all tab content then display the current
    $(tabContainers).hide().filter(this.hash).show();

    window.location.hash = this.hash;

    //prevent page from skipping but also prevents # from appearing in address bar
    return false;

});
```

Note that this will add a page into the browser history, allowing the user to use the back and forward buttons to change the hash. You should ideally also look at handling that.

Comment: Thanks but that has the same effect as removing return false.  The page skips when the link is clicked.